# Chef - Tagging a server with a recipe if variable1 matches anything in variable2

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

So I am trying to Tag a Server in Chef by stating, if variable1 is equal to any value in variable2, to tag the server using this line of code -

**Variables and code in recipe default.rb -**

```
node_gateway = node['network']['default_gateway']
dmz_gateways = node['tagging_test']['dmz_default_gateways']

tag('dmz') if node_gateway == dmz_gateways.any?
```

**Attribute in default.rb -**

```
default['tagging_test']['dmz_default_gateways'] = %w(192.168.0.1 192.168.1.1 192.168.2.1)
```

However this produces no errors, but doesn't do anything either.

I have confirmed I can tag servers by simply doing -

```
tag('dmz')
```

I am thinking I may have the use of .any? setup incorrectly.  Perhaps my attribute values are wrongly setup as well?

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good except the if condition.

`dmz_gateways.any?` return true and you are comparing it with `node_gateway == true` which return false

You can right something like:

```
node_gateway = node['network']['default_gateway']
dmz_gateways = node['tagging_test']['dmz_default_gateways']

tag('dmz') if dmz_gateways.include?(node_gateway)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Thank you!!! :D